# How to find the corresponding maven artifact/gradle module of an Android class from the API Docs?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Is there a way to find out which `maven` artifact or `gradle` module i have to include if i want to use a specific Android class from the Android `API` documentation class?

For example, if i encounter the new SelectionTracker class (on
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker), then how do i find out that i need to add the following androidx module

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.0.0'
}
```

to my gradle file?

I only know this from reading tutorial websites, because the Api webpage only seems to mention the java package names. At least i found 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings
to retrieve the corresponding androidx module whenever some older tutorials only mention the older support-library module names.

Comment: I usually search in google for `<SOME_CLASS> gradle` or `<SOME_CLASS> maven`

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the best i can do, although had hoped that there were direct links in the Api pages, which i had missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no golden rule for that.

In Maven Projects (for which I use IntelliJ), I usually mention the class in code (which will cause a compiler error) and then open the quick fixes using `Alt+Enter`. In there, IntelliJ will either offer the possibility to import the class, if it was found on the class path or offer me to "Add [a] Maven dependency". If I select "Add Maven dependency", a search tool will come up which allows me to search maven central by class name. However, I experienced many cases where the search wouldn't find anything. I suspect that Android Studio has a similar capability for gradle (since Android Studio is built on top of IntelliJ).

If that doesn't work, the java package name should give you hints about the group id oft the dependency, as they use the same naming convention: For example, the class `com.github.vatbub.randomusers.Generator` is located in the package `com.github.vatbub.randomusers`. The corresponding maven artifact has the group id `com.github.vatbub` and the artifact id `randomusers`. Again, this is not always the case, but it can give you some hints.

If that doesn't help either, Google (or [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/)) is your friend ;)